# How to identify character before putting it on EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

While entering text on edit text I want it should start with `'#'` and later contain `[0-9] and [a-z]`.
If user tries to enter the first character other than `'#'` it should not display on `EditText`. After '#' if user enters character other than `[0-9] and [a-z]` it also should not display on `EditText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case, it would be preferable to use [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) instead of `TextWatcher`

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            // You will need to handle condition for 1st character should be #.
            if(i == 0)
            {
                if(!source.charAt(i).equals("#"))
                    return "";
            }
            else if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
myEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Refer: [Allow only Letter and Digit in Edittext](http://www.almadevelop.com/2011/11/android-how-to-use-inputfilter-with.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: your code works perfect, but it allows to enter more # if user enters # first..In want single # at start only..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `textWatcher` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html in method `onTextChange()` you can check what was inputted by the user

Answer (score 0):

You need KeyPress and KeyDown events

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
         /* This is a sample for handling the Enter button */
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Remember to implement OnKeyListener and to set your listener YourView.setOnKeyListener(this);
The second possibility would be:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     switch (keyCode) {
     case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
        /* Sample for handling the Menu button globally */
        return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Learn more about the Key Events [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html).